# Converting a time with certain offset in utc time with zero offset in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

lets say we have this code in javascript:

```
var format = dateFns.format

const d = new Date();
const f = format(d,'YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00Z');  // "2021-07-28T00:00:00+02:00"
```

The offset should be subtracted in the above time so that a UTC time results with Zulu or 0 offset. It should look like this:

```
2021-07-27T22:00Z or 2021-07-27T22:00+00:00
```

How do I achieve this in Javascript?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just want to print the date as ISO? see [`Date#toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Comment: `console.log(new Date().toISOString())`

Answer (score 2):

Like it is answered in the comments section, the solution is:

```
new Date(f).toISOString() // 2021-07-27T22:00:00.000Z
```